# Performing side effects on NGXS Forms UpdateFormValue

Tags: angular, ngxs

My application uses NGXS Forms Plugin and I'd like to trigger certain API calls when a value in my form changes.

Is this correct to do the following? If not, what would be the recommended way to do so?

```js
@Action(UpdateFormValue)
public doStuff(ctx: StateContext<any>, { payload }: UpdateFormValue) {
    // logic
}
```

This seems to work, but then I'm unable to see update forms value action in Redux developer tools, which makes me wonder if I am doing it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're on the right track!

NGXS dispatches `UpdateFormValue` under the hood after `valueChanges` stream emits any event, basically, there is nothing supernatural :D

My only comment is you would want to cancel previously uncompleted asynchronous job when the new `UpdateFormValue` action is dispatched, so you've got to use `cancelUncompleted` option:

```js
@Action(UpdateFormValue, { cancelUncompleted: true })
public doStuff(ctx, action) {}
```

---

Also, the `UpdateFormValue` action is not dispatched immediately as the `valueChanges` stream is piped via `debounceTime`. If you don't want this stream to be piped via `debounceTime` you have to provide `ngxsFormDebounce` binding that should be less than `0`, something like:

```html
<form ngxsForm="blah-blah" [ngxsFormDebounce]="-1">
```

Or you can explicitly set `updateOn` option of your `FormGroup` to the `blur` or `submit`, then `debounceTime` will be also ignored.

Comment: Thanks! Also thanks for the for cancelation tip  didn't know about it.